# What is the correct structure to represent a list of movie showtimes on the same page?

Tags: schema.org, json-ld

I am building a website to reference movie showtimes.

The site shows a now playing page with a list of movies, each movie has a page with the upcoming showtimes.

I added some structured data to enhance the way search engines sees the data on my website.

Here is what I have so far:

```json
{
  "@context": "https://schema.org",
  "@type": "ItemList",
  "numberOfItems": 2,
  "itemListElement": [
    {
      "@type": "ListItem",
      "name": "Screening Event 1",
      "position": 1,
      "item": {
        "@context": "https://schema.org",
        "@type": "ScreeningEvent",
        "startDate": "2021-09-18T15:15:00.000Z",
        "url": "http://localhost:3000/film/Boite-noire/663260#6144ab7a22b6d900165aa836",
        "inLanguage": "fr",
        "location": {
          "@context": "https://schema.org",
          "@type": "MovieTheater",
          "name": "Pathé Tunis City",
          "url": "http://localhost:3000/medium/pathe-tunis-city"
        },
        "workPresented": {
          "@context": "https://schema.org",
          "@type": "Movie",
          "name": "Boîte noire",
          "image": "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300_and_h450_bestv2/jIfFFC4YwiI8TVaGtbl1eT9BRaI.jpg",
          "url": "http://localhost:3000/film/Boite-noire/663260",
          "sameAs": "https://imdb.com/title/tt10341034",
          "director": {
            "@type": "Person",
            "name": "Yann Gozlan"
          }
        }
      }
    },
    {
      "@type": "ListItem",
      "name": "Screening Event 2",
      "position": 2,
      "item": {
        "@context": "https://schema.org",
        "@type": "ScreeningEvent",
        "startDate": "2021-09-18T20:15:00.000Z",
        "url": "http://localhost:3000/film/Boite-noire/663260#6144ab8522b6d900165aa837",
        "inLanguage": "fr",
        "location": {
          "@context": "https://schema.org",
          "@type": "MovieTheater",
          "name": "Pathé Tunis City",
          "url": "http://localhost:3000/medium/pathe-tunis-city"
        },
        "workPresented": {
          "@context": "https://schema.org",
          "@type": "Movie",
          "name": "Boîte noire",
          "image": "https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w300_and_h450_bestv2/jIfFFC4YwiI8TVaGtbl1eT9BRaI.jpg",
          "url": "http://localhost:3000/film/Boite-noire/663260",
          "sameAs": "https://imdb.com/title/tt10341034",
          "director": {
            "@type": "Person",
            "name": "Yann Gozlan"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Is there a better way to represent this kind of information without repeating data ?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because SEO QUESTIONS ARE OFF-TOPIC. Only programming-related SEO questions are acceptable on Stack Overflow. Non-programming SEO questions should be asked on Webmasters.SE at https://webmasters.stackexchange.com. Please delete your question first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion gave the google guide for **[Carousel --> Single, all-in-one-page list](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/structured-data/carousel#all-in-one)**:

```js
{
"@context": "https://schema.org",
"@type": "Movie",
...
"@id":"https://cinema.com/lordofrings.html",
"name":"Lord of the rings",
"subjectOf":{
"@type": "ItemList",
"itemListElement": [
{
"@type": "ListItem",
"position": "1",
"item": {
"@type": "ScreeningEvent",
"url": "https://cinema.com/lordofrings.html#15",
"startDate": "2021-09-18T15:00:00+01:00"
}
},
{
"@type": "ListItem",
"position": "2",
"item": {
"@type": "ScreeningEvent",
"url": "https://cinema.com/lordofrings.html#18",
"startDate": "2021-09-18T18:00:00+01:00"
}
}
]
}
}
```

For ellipsis, set the required movie info and add all the required and recommended properties for the **[Google Rich Results Test](https://search.google.com/test/rich-results)**.

Comment: Thank you @nikant25 that's exactly what I was lookin for